# How to programmatically request a web page from an application which uses ADFS

Tags: java, oauth, saml, adfs, ws-federation

There is this web page served by a web application which uses Microsoft ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services) for access control. I can request this web page using a browser and if I'm not logged into ADFS I'll get redirected to the ADFS login form page. After submitting my credentials (username and password) I get redirected back to the page I originally requested. This all works fine.

Now, I would like to use Java to programmatically request this web page and handle the single sign-on with ADFS.

To be clear: this will be a simple CLI application requesting a web page and I'm fine with entering the username and password into the configuration of this application if required. (Maybe some kind of token can be obtained and configured instead?) The web page I want to access is just a regular HTML document, not something fancy like a web service.

I've been reading about the technologies supported by ADFS, like WS-Federation, SAML and OAuth, but after reading about these for a couple of hours and checking out all kinds of libraries that implement these technologies (Apache CXF, Apache Rampart, OpenSAML, Spring SAML, google-oauth-java-client, etc.) I still have the following questions:

- Which of the protocols supported by ADFS can or should I use for this use case?
- Which Java library (or libraries) would help me implement my use case?

There are so many standards, technologies and acronyms in this realm... I feel a little lost.

Comment: There are too many unknowns to be able to answer this properly. On the same domain as ADFS? Different? Do you have control over the ADFS configuration? With what you have here, I would suggest OAuth and the Google client.

Answer (score 2):

ADFS is a solution for web-browser based Single Sign-on. Which means that it requires a web browser for user's session management. All the authentication schemes like SAML, WS-Federation, OAuth requires a browser redirect to Identity Source (in your case ADFS).

If you want a CLI application to authenticate against your ADFS server, consider using some of the underlying protocols like [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) (it will directly connect to your Active Directory Server for authentication) or [WS-Trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Trust) (SOAP-based protocol) or [RADIUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS).

Answer (score 0):

Java tends towards SAML-p so you need a SAML stack.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

Wrt. OAuth2, ADFS 3.0 only handles Web API, not web sites e.g. via OpenID Connect.